# Call function only once after a map()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having an issue on Nodejs, I need to call a function only once when `item.IS_RACING === 1`

look

```
    _.map(recordsets, function(items) {
      return _.map(items, function(item) {
        if (item.IS_RACING === 1) {
          _this.getRacing();
        }
      });
    });
```

I have that `_this.getRacing();` which is being called everytime the conditional is `true`, but if there is 20 items with `IS_RACING === 1`, so the function `_this.getRacing();` is going to be call 20 times. I need something like, once the app detects when the first `IS_RACING === 1` comes up, then fires `_this.getRacing();` only once.

Any recommendation ?

Comment: How much do you care that you use `_.map` to do this? I think a regular JS for loop may be in order.

Comment: `_.map()` is the wrong API. Use `_.some()` to check whether anything any item in the list has the flag set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `Pointy` pointed out (sorry) in the comments, you really don't want to use `map()` to do this.

Think of the problem in terms of how you would explain it to another developer.

> If any of the record sets has an item that is racing, I want to call `getRacing()`.

Now, write code that represents your intent.

```
var somethingIsRacing = _.some(recordsets, function(items) {
  return _.some(items, function(item) {
    return item.IS_RACING === 1;
  });
});
if(somethingIsRacing) {
  _this.getRacing();
}
```

This code follows a principle called Command-Query Separation, where you first query to find the information you need using a *functional* style of programming, then you perform actions that will have side-effects using an *imperative* programming style.

Comment: I like this because it has a better semantic meaning and doesn't rely as much on side effects (as opposed to just looping and setting some external flag). +1

Answer (score 0):

A flag variable usually does the trick:

```
var getRacingCalled = false;
_.map(recordsets, function(items) {
  return _.map(items, function(item) {
    if (item.IS_RACING === 1 && !getRacingCalled) {
      _this.getRacing();
      getRacingCalled = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @epascarello it has already been said in the comments when I wrote my answer, so I added a more generic flag solution.

Comment: @epascarello why you have to be like that ? hahaha and Shomz, thank you, have a nice one :)

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer, no problem! :)

Comment: Why? Because a lot of times OPs pick answers like this because they just work. Sort of like opening up a window with a hammer. It works, but there is a better way to do it. (FYI: I am not the -1)

Comment: Agreed, though I think you went too far with the window/hammer metaphor since the flags are way way older and more widely used than the specific method that works only in this case. So because of the overhead, I'd correct the metaphor to opening a window with a remote. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with a closure:

```
var closure = (function() {
    var fired = false;
    return function (item) {
        if (!fired && item.IS_RACING === 1) {
            fired = true;
            _this.getRacing();
        }
    }; 
})();

_.map(recordsets, function(items) {
      return _.map(items, closure(item));
});
```